# See what bots are active on a Slack instance

Tags: slack, bot

My company is using Slack enterprise. I can see that there are a few bots running (installed?), like "/todo".

How can I see all of the bots that are being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list all connected Slack apps and bots on their Manage Apps screen. That's present in `<team url>`/apps/manage.